# Programmatically export Site Content -> All Pages urls using Google Analytics API

Tags: php, mysql, google-analytics

I was curious, is it possible to use the Google Analytics API to export the list of urls/paths from "Site Content" -> "All Pages" in Google Analytics?

Ideally, I'd like to export this list from Google Analytics, parse it out, and save it into a MySQL database. Parsing it, in addition to saving it into MySQL isn't where my issue is. I'm just not sure if it's possible to programmatically export that list using PHP.

Thanks,
Brandon

Comment: Yes, of course. Frankly the simplest way is to use the Google Analytics Query Explorer and download the report als Excel (tsv actually). Select pagePath as dimension and at least one metric (pageViews would be appropriate). Click "Run Query" and then scroll to the bottom and click "download tsv" (https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/).

Comment: @EikePierstorff Thank you, I'll give it a try and report back shortly.